# R Shiny export two dataframes into two sheets in same excel sheet

Tags: r, excel, shiny, export

I'm trying to export two different dataframes into two sheets within the same excel workbook from R Shiny. I have tried a number of different solutions, but can't seem to get any to work.

```
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "My_File.xlsx",
    content = function(file) {
      wb = createWorkbook()

      addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 1")
      addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet 2")

      writeData(wb, "Sheet 1", exportData(), startCol = 1, rowNames = FALSE)
      writeData(wb, "Sheet 2", ALEGR(), startCol = 1, rowNames = FALSE)

      saveWorkbook(wb, "My_File.xlsx")
    }
  )
```

Gives a 404 not found error.

```
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "test.xlsx",
    content = function(file) {
      write.xlsx(exportData(), file, sheetName="sheet1", row.names=FALSE)
      write.xlsx(ALEGR(), file, sheetName="sheet2", append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
    }
  )
```

Only saves the `ALEGR()` dataframe with "Sheet2", no "Sheet1".

It doesn't really matter to me if it is a .csv or a .xlsx, but I can't seem to get either to work. Simply put, I would like the `exportData()` to be on sheet1, and `ALEGR()` to be on sheet2 of the same workbook.

Thanks!

Comment: In second chunk, try wrapping list() to return both calls: `list(write.xlsx(...), write.xlsx(...))` since last line appears to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be achievable with `library(xlsx)`:

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "My_File.xlsx",
    content = function(file) {
        wb <- createWorkbook()

        sheet_1 <- createSheet(wb, "exportData()")

        sheet_2 <- createSheet(wb, "ALEGR()")

        addDataFrame(
            exportData(),
            sheet         = sheet_1,
            row.names     = FALSE
        )

        addDataFrame(
            ALEGR(),
            sheet         = sheet_2,
            row.names     = FALSE
        )

        saveWorkbook(wb, file)
    } 
)
```